# My touchpad isn't working properly. Having trouble with Ubuntu 20.04 and my Thinkpad T450s. It's pretty weird situation and I need some help

Tags: kernel, mouse, touchpad, thinkpad

Ah,I think I need to explain everything in detail. I am a Lenovo Thinkpad user and mine is T450s model. I am mentioning cause I think some of the Thinkpad users having trouble with it(Saw couple of posts).

**Here is the Details:** We know normally Thinkpad has  touchpad with three red buttons at the top including a trackpoint which is also red. Couple of days ago I was going to use my upper buttons for left click and suddenly I noticed that my cursor was stuck with folder icon and couldn't separate it and I couldn't do a single click using my touchpad. Only if I press "Esc" then it gets separated and keyboard and touchpad don't work after I press "Esc". I mean nothing happens. Totally null and void.

I tried couple of tests and it acts strangely. Such as:

**Note:** Upper three buttons don't work in both Windows and Ubuntu.

**Test 1:** If I restart pc and after logging in, the Right Button at Bottom works only for first click and then if I click for the second time on any folder or icon or any application, it just gets stuck with it and doesn't respond until I restart or logout.

**Test 2:** When I use usb mouse, it works pretty fine in ubuntu 20.04 without clicking on my touchpad for a single time. I mean if I restart and use usb mouse without any clicking touchpad buttons it works fine.

**Test 3:** When I shift back to the Windows 10, only Bottom Left button is working as Right click button and right portion of touchpad doesn't work!. But usb mouse works pretty fine.

**Test 4:** There is pretty weird thing I noticed. If I use kernel version of ubuntu 20.04 with "Linux 5.4.0.59 generic" instead of "Linux 5.4.0.39 generic", it gives problem only first click. But if I do logout and loginn once again, the bottom right and bottom left buttons work pretty fine of my touchpad. Even while I am writing this post I am using my touchpad working with bottoms of touchpad.

I have never experienced such thing before. I am not sure if it is a problem with hardware or touchpad or just anything internal I don't know. I thought it would be wise if posted it here and share with Ubuntu users.

So this is all about it. I will be looking forward to your response guys. Thank you.

Comment: I own a T450 which is largely identical and have seen no such issues. This sounds (mouse buttons sticking) like hardware problem. Given the laptop is 5 years old, it might be worth taking it apart and checking connections and cleanliness of the buttons. Dust and dirt can really cause similar to what you're describing.

Comment: @popey Are you sure that dust could cause for that problem? –